# Cumulative distinct count of the last X days

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, distinct, postgresql-10

I'm using PostGreSQL 10.12 with the following table:

```
|test_name|result |report_time|
|    B    |failed |29/11/2020 |
|    A    |error  |29/12/2020 |
|    B    |passed |29/12/2020 |
|    C    |error  |29/12/2020 |
|    A    |passed |30/12/2020 |
|    B    |failure|30/12/2020 |
|    A    |error  |31/12/2020 |
```

My goad it to get the cumulative distinct count of all "flaky" tests, i.e, tests that don't pass 100% of the time and don't fail 100% of the time in the past month, per date.
So the result of the above table will be:

```
|report_time|sum|comments
|31/12/2020 | 2 | range (31/12 -> 1/12), A (error + passed) + B (failure + passed) = 2
|30/12/2020 | 2 | range (30/12 -> 30/11), B (failure + passed) + A (error + passed) = 2
|29/12/2020 | 1 | range (29/12 -> 29/11), B (passed + failure) = 1
|29/11/2020 | 0 | range (29/11 -> 29/10), No flaky tests (only a single failure) = 0
```

I'm pretty new to PostGres and I created the following query:

```
SELECT 
report_time::date, 
COUNT(count) OVER (
    ORDER BY report_time::date ASC 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    )
FROM (
    SELECT report_time::date, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT test_name) AS count 
    FROM tests 
    WHERE report_time > now() - interval '30 days'
    GROUP by 1 
    HAVING COUNT(case when result in ('failure', 'error') then 1 else null end) > 0
    AND COUNT(case when result='passed' then 1 else null end) > 0
) as aggrQuery
ORDER BY report_time::date DESC;
```

But its result is the of each row by 1, which is incorrect.
Also, due to PostGres version (10.12) I can't use the `range between preceding and current row` function, as it doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Postgres does not support the range clause, then I would recommend subqueries:

```
select t.report_date,
    (
        select count(*)
        from (
            select 1
            from tests t1
            where 
                t1.report_time >= t.report_date - interval 30 day 
                and t1.report_time < report_date + interval 1 day 
            group by t1.rest_name
            having min(t1.result) <> max(t1.result)
        ) t
    ) as res
from (select distinct report_time::date as report_date from tests) t
order by t.report_date
```